# how many times this patent has been cited until now?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US2708656](https://www.google.com/patents/US2708656)

Comment: according to Google Patents, 235 times

Comment: @daniel With a couple steps of how you found it, that would make a reasonable answer to this.